# How to save page content on client with all form data as HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Is there a way to save a page to HTML file, saving the client's text entered into form fields,  *after* the page source has already been downloaded to client ? Is there a way to do this completely on the client side?

For example in Chrome, only text that was entered on document load will get saved into the HTML.

Comment: Where do you want to save the page with the completed fields? On the client or server?

Comment: Set the value **attribute** of text inputs to the current value of the input, then the value will be in the innerHTML. Of course this will replace any default value that was set in the original markup.

Comment: I just 2 days ago read of such extension for Firefox but can't remember its name

Comment: Of course you couldn't resume the execution from the saved page if it had javascript, would be next to impossible.

Comment: Only RobG understood the question....

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that you're trying to cache your page on the client in the form of an HTML file. Browsers do provide your page direct access to the file system for security reasons, but they allow you access to the `cookie` storage. I suggest that you save your form data in cookies if you want it to be persistent between page loads from the same machine. Then on load perform a check for the `cookie` and if it exists load the form data from there.